# Only MainActivity buttons works

Tags: java, android, android-button

The application's MainActivity has 5 buttons, all works perfectly, but when I call a third screen, the application stops. I don't know why this is happening.

```
package com.example.victorsales.testeapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class teladoimc extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teladoimc);
    }

    public void telaadulto(View v){
        Intent tela = new Intent(this, imcadulto.class);
        startActivity(tela);
    }



}
```

And here is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_teladoimc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.victorsales.testeapp.teladoimc">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/ndice_de_massa_corporal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/importante_adultos_abrange_um_grupo_de_pessoas_com_idade_entre_20_e_60_anos_idosos_abrange_um_grupo_de_pessoas_maiores_que_60_anos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt7"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/MyTitleTextStyle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/adulto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt6"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="telaadulto" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/idoso"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt7"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt6"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="telaidoso" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It was to go to the third activity, but when I click the button it for the application.

Comment: Do you set the `onClick` in xml for that second layout?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue:

```
public class teladoimc extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickLister {

Button bt6;
Button bt7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teladoimc);
    bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt6);
    bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt7);
    bt6.setOnClickListener(this); //you need to add this for clicks to work.
    bt7.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bt6) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(teladoimc.this, imcadulto.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bt7) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(teladoimc.this, imcidoso.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

The problem with your code is that you have no implemented the `View.OnClickListener` in your class but have overridden its `onClick` method. This is needed:

```
implements View.OnClickLister
```

Also, for an interface to work, you first need to supply the interface object via `view.setOnClickListener(object)` which here means your Class which implements `View.OnClickListener`.

```
bt6.setOnClickListener(this);
bt7.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: This is the problem, it does not acknowledge error, the application works normally, but when clicking the button of the second activity it does not exercise the function

Comment: I already try to use the same code used at the MainActivity, and still not working, i've tried your way and not work :(

Comment: add your second activity's layout code and update other code.

Comment: I put the layout in the description of the problem, was that what you wanted?

Comment: What are you using setContentView inside onClick?

Comment: To call the third activity

Comment: Oh no. You need to use startActivity() method to go to the third acvity from this activity.. setContentView is for setting a layout to the current activity.

Comment: bt6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(teladoimc.this, imcadulto.class);
                startActivity(it)

Answer (score 0):

you must use `setOnClickListener` for bt6 and 7 just like you did for the other ones